# Making subscriber listen to all observer changes

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, system.reactive

I am just starting out with ReactiveX in an existing Xamarin.iOS project. I wanted to adapt my previous searchcontroller/uitableview solution into one which used reactivex for practice.

Here is my current approach:

```
var dataStream =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<UISearchBarTextChangedEventArgs>(
            ev => searchController.SearchBar.TextChanged += ev,
            ev => searchController.SearchBar.TextChanged -= ev)
        .Select(o => o.EventArgs.SearchText)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
        .Synchronize()
        .Select(t =>
        {
            var lookup = new Lookup(prefix: t);
            smartyStreetsClient.Send(lookup);
            var data = new List<Suggestion>(lookup.Result);
            return data.ToObservable().ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);
        })
        .Switch();

dataStream.Subscribe(o =>
{
    suggestions.Add(o);
    TableView.Source = new ATableSource(suggestions);
    TableView.ReloadData();
});
```

While this works at first, the subscriber is not listening in on any more changes to my observable besides the first (observer is successfully getting ran on every text change). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do a little search for James World .SPY custom operator here on S.O. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please?

```
var dataStream =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<UISearchBarTextChangedEventArgs>(
            ev => searchController.SearchBar.TextChanged += ev,
            ev => searchController.SearchBar.TextChanged -= ev)
        .Select(o => o.EventArgs.SearchText)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .SelectMany(t => Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            var lookup = new Lookup(prefix: t);
            smartyStreetsClient.Send(lookup);
            var data = new List<Suggestion>(lookup.Result);
            return data;
        }))
        .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

I'm not able to test your code, so it might require a bit of fiddling.